# Errors about scanf and printf expected types

Tags: c, structure

My issue is coming from the `%c` name input, I am getting an error that it is expecting type `char *`  but has type `char * [15]` for the `scanf` function. I am also getting an error in the `printf` where the `%c` expects `int`  but has type `char *`. I am still quite new at this so if it could be explained as simply as possible that would be amazing.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Student {
    int StudentID;
    char Name[15];
    float Mark1;
    float Mark2;
    float Mark3;
} a;

int main() {
    float ave;
    printf("Please input Student's ID \n");
    scanf("%d", &a.StudentID);
    printf("Please input Student's name. \n");
    scanf(" %c", &a.Name);
    printf("Input Mark 1. \n");
    scanf("%f", &a.Mark1);
    printf("Input Mark 2. \n");
    scanf("%f", &a.Mark2);
    printf("Input Mark 3. \n");
    scanf("%f", &a.Mark3);
    ave = (a.Mark1 + a.Mark2 + a.Mark3) / 3;

    printf("Student Detail\nStudent ID: %d\nName: %c\nMark 1: %.2f\n Mark 2: %.2f\n Mark 3: %.2f\nAverage: %.2f\n",
           a.StudentID, a.Name, a.Mark1, a.Mark2, a.Mark3, ave);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%c` reads a single character, `%s` reads a string. `%14s` reads up to 14 characters leaving space for the terminator so you do not overflow the buffer. Since `Name` is an array you do not need `&` before it to turn it into a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is related to the difference between an array of chars and a single char.

The `%c` format only reads in one character at a time.

If you wish to read a string of characters use `%s` and it will read until a whitespace. (Please make sure you don't try to read a name more than 14 characters long into your 15 character buffer)

In more depth, your `char Name[15]` is actually a pointer to a series of chars in memory. You are accidentally trying to change to pointer itself, instead of the chars that it points to. This is why the compiler expects a `char *` .

Instead if you truly meant to only read one char you could use

```
scanf(" %c", &a.Name[0]);
```

to place the character in the first block of the Name array.

If this is too complicated don't worry, it will all come eventually :)

For now I think `%s` will suffice.
You can use `%14s` to be extra safe.

Also don't forget to use `%s` in the final printf as well

Comment: *For now I think `%s` will suffice.*: not really. Make it `%14s` for a safe conversion.

Comment: Apologies for the mistakes, edited the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your scanf() call, %c tells scanf() to accept a single character. But your argument is a character array. C is a low-level language; it's not smart enough to realize you wanted a string (char array) as input. You have to tell it by using %s instead of %c.

Comment: It's not C that isn't smart enough. It is the coder who did not express the intent.